# Smooth transition to standard 3D view orientation

Tags: c++, math, opengl, c++11

Currently, I have a mechanism to orient the view to standard orientation by modifying the model view matrix.
I would like to enhance the user experience by providing a smooth animation that will take the user from the current view orientation to the standard view orientation with a smooth transition -> (constant rate of change of direction).
The transition should ideally take less than 500 milliseconds.

I have the following already implemented.

- A matrix class
- quaternion (I can extract matrix from this)

I can extract the current view direction and I know the view direction of all standard views.

My questions:

1. Should the user be allowed to interact and change the view orientation while the transition is in progress. I think yes, but not sure of the behaviour. I do not want the app to freeze irrespective of the state of the system.
2. How do I maintain constant rate of change of direction with acceleration and deceleration at the start and end respectively.
3. How should frames be rendered while the transition is in progress (500 ms). Is there an elegant way of 
   doing this in C++11 using std::thread.

Comment: If it's fast, you can just lock input for a while. You don't have to use a thread, if you implement your own timer function (probably will be simpler). And to b) - quaternions were made for that

Comment: It did not seem to be the right thing to do as the user may find the system unresponsive while the transition is on. Unfortunately, there are several other simultaneous updates like changes in scene that should be addressed by threads. I am not sure if C++11 has a built in timer. I am happy to write one if there is nothing available from C++11 / STL.

Comment: Boost has good timer. I think you could also use `std::promise` in this sort of value modification, but I'm not exactly sure how

Comment: Part 1 might make a good question for [ux.se], if there's not already something like that there. I've had fun in the past playing with amplifiers with powered volume knobs (controlled by the remote control), seeing what happens when the knob is trying to turn one way while I'm physically turning it the other. It seems to me this is a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already handling user input while rendering, there shouldn't be a need for a separate thread. If you want the user to still have control just don't let them control the view matrix directly - rather a target view matrix and simply nudge the current view matrix towards the target a part of the way each frame.

This will complicate the smooth acceleration/deceleration though - say, you start out with a small acceleration, build up speed, and then the user moves the camera: do you start again with a low speed, or do you continue with the same? This is a design decision, but I think the controls would feel weird if the speed the view rotated at changed midway. Also - if you have acceleration/deceleration the rate of change wouldn't be constant by definition, so you really need to decide what you want, possibly try both solutions and see if it "feels right" for a lack of a better phrase.

Comment: Actually, in terms of rate of change of direction, I tried constant change rate and it felt jerky at the start and end. So I am planning to implement a second approach where I accelerate constantly till the half way stage and then to decelerate to 0 change. I am performing this on the main thread now and this stops the scene from updating. I am still looking for an "elegant" solution. 

However, I am still not sure whether to block to user input.